# Gnuplot - EPS terminal producing extra characters

Tags: latex, terminal, gnuplot, eps

I have  gnuplot file that is outputting quite nicely in EPS but I'm suffering some issues when it comes to the labels. For some reason, a random figure (') is being inserted before the each label. This isn't being produced in a PNG export.

Example [gnuplot error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvvhZ.png)

The gnuplot file is below

```
set term postscript eps enhanced 
set datafile separator ","
set datafile missing "NULL"
set decimal locale
set output 'Average_Costs_Plotted.eps'
set grid
set key left
set ytics nomirror
set xtics nomirror
set format y "£%'.0f"
set ylabel "Total Loss Estimate \n Based on Average Cost Per m^2"
set xlabel "Area Damaged m^2"
plot "Average_Costs_Upto_10000mSQM.csv" using 1:2 axis x1y1 title 'Industrial Processing' w l lw 2
```

Comment: If I replace the pound sign with a dollar sign, the extra quote disappears. Maybe gnuplot's postscript driver is not able to handle unicode?

Comment: It may appear to be the case :(

However, I almost have epslatex export working - the only problem I have currently with that is sizing of the key and nt being able to seperate the key from the graph (I set it to display outside and the graph is stretched)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well that'll teach me to RTFM.

Postscript doesn't support unicode as mentioned above - however there are octal codes for symbols to insert them.

The £ is input by using the code \243